# Using an adapter in a fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, adapter

I am trying to use a `GridView` in a `Fragment` and then using an `Adapter` to populate it with buttons. My code currently is:

Inside the MainActivity:

```
public static class MiscFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public MiscFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc_fragment,
                container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new MiscAdapter(this.getActivity()));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My adapter class:

```
public class MiscAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public MiscAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mButtons.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button myButton; 

    if(convertView == null){
        myButton = new Button(mContext);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,55));
        myButton.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }
    else{
        myButton = (Button) convertView;
    }

    myButton.setText(mButtons[position]);
    myButton.setId(position);
    return null;
}

private String[] mButtons = {
        "Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4",
        "Button5", "Button6", "Button7", "Button8",
        "Button9", "Button10"

};

}
```

I believe my error is at: `gridview.setAdapter(new MiscAdapter(this.getActivity()));`

I think I need to pass a `Context` in there but I'm not sure if that is how I am supposed to do it or if `Fragments` even use `Context`. Right now it is throwing a Null Pointer Exception.

Stack trace:

```
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at         android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1028)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at  android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1389)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 18:29:19.541: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not assigning created View to  `convertView` if convertView is `null` .change `getView` method as:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button myButton; 

    if(convertView == null){
        myButton = new Button(mContext);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,55));
        myButton.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

        convertView=myButton;  //>>> assign myButton to convertView
    }
    else{
        myButton = (Button) convertView;
    }
     ....
    return convertView; /// return View from here
}
```

Comment: I made the change and I'm still getting the same error with the same stack trace

Comment: @rsayles3 : try to run project after clean and rebuild from Project -> Clean

Comment: Did that, and reset Eclipse and still same result

Comment: This is correct but the return is convertView. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In your OnCreateView the parent activity is not yet available, so it's unsafe to make getActivity() call there.

Move your code to onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.misc_fragment,
            container, false);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    gridview.setAdapter(new MiscAdapter(getActivity()));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I can't define `gridview` without having `inflater` which comes from `onCreateView`

Comment: Yes you can, store reference to your GridView inside fragment. Inflate grid in OnCreateView. Set adapter in OnActivityCreated

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I did that and I got this error: 

05-09 19:04:06.580: E/AndroidRuntime(529): android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment MiscFragment{412cd950 #0 id=0x7f080000 android:switcher:2131230720:0} did not call through to super.onActivityCreated()

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. You should make call to super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 1):

Your `getView` method returns null. Shouldn't you return `convertView` after inflating it if necessary ?